# code opening IE but need safari and Firefox

Tags: firefox, safari

How can I get this code to work with Safari or Firefox?

```
Public Function getGoogDistanceTime(startAddr As String, startCity As String, _
startState As String, startZip As String, endAddr As String, _
endCity As String, endState As String, endZip As String) As String
Dim sURL As String
Dim BodyTxt As String
Dim apan As String
Dim oXH As Object
    sURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr="
    sURL = sURL & Replace(startAddr, " ", "+") & ",+" & Replace(startCity, " ", "+") & ",+" & startState
    sURL = sURL & "&daddr=" & Replace(endAddr, " ", "+") & ",+" & Replace(endCity, " ", "+") & ",+" & endState
    sURL = sURL & "&hl=en"
    Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
            With oXH
              .Open "get", sURL, False
              .Send
              BodyTxt = .RESPONSETEXT
            End With

            apan = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(apan)
            apan = Mid(BodyTxt, InStr(1, BodyTxt, "<div class=""altroute-rcol altroute-info"">") + 49, 200)
            apan = Left(apan, InStr(1, apan, "</span>    </div>") - 1)
            apan = Replace(apan, "</span>", "")
            apan = Replace(apan, "<span>", "")
            getGoogDistanceTime = apan
    Set oXH = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is written in VBScript, which is an Internet Explorer-only language.  You need to rewrite it in JavaScript, which is understood by all the browsers.

You're also using IE-only code to do AJAX, using `msxml2`.  That will need changing to use more generic AJAX code, using an `XMLHttpRequest` object.

I don't know what `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim()` is, but you'll need to find a JavaScript alternative.